# Got "no operations specified" when installing emacs24 package

Tags: emacs24

I am trying Emacs 24 on Ubuntu 13.04, and find it offers package system. I installed muse, google-c-style and nginx mode successfully. But soon I cannot install any other packages. 
When use i key, no mark, when typing x key, emacs outputs "no operations specified"

How to debug this?

Comment: It happens on my computer in office now. When try to install ebrowse, it outputs the same message

Comment: Try starting emacs with emacs -Q  then M-x package-list-packages and try again. If that works the problem is to do with your configuration.